# deploy app on appengine on port 8761

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm deploying a Java app that runs on port 8761, and works fine on localhost.
Although when I push to App Engine flexible environment, I get a HTTP 502 server error.

Here is my `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: java
env: flex

service: eureka

runtime_config:
  jdk: openjdk8

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: ignore
  secure: always

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 2
```

The log from gcloud is fine, server is running, but my request doesn't seems to hit the app at all.

I noticed that if I run on port 8080, it works. For now, it is not a problem change the default port to 8080, but I would like to understand why I'm not able to run it on 8761

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to use the [network settings section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#network_settings) in the `app.yaml` config file:

```
network:
  forwarded_ports:
    - 8761/tcp
```

You might also need to set [firewall rules in the Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls).

Comment: did all of this, added the firewall rules, but when I access the app address I still get the 502 (guess this was expected, since it is not running on 8080) and when I access on https://app.appspot.com:8761 nothing happens, I get "Site can't be reached" like if it were offline

Comment: oh..when I access the ip address of the machine instead going through app.appspot.com it works!

Comment: Hmm my assumption would have been that the host name would have worked as well. I'll check on that and document it if that is in fact the expected condition.

Comment: actually seems like a known bug...can you confirm that? edit: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35898669

Comment: Hi Luiz, I updated the documentation to reflect that the forwarded ports are only available through direct connections and not through the domain name. The forwarded ports are today intended for use with attaching debuggers or profilers, rather than for load balanced requests that would otherwise go through the domain name and global load balancer (and autoscaler).

Comment: great! Thanks so much @BrettJ