# how to run an application on port different than 8080 on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Hi have this lib which runs a Jerry server on port 8001. Hi can I deploy it on GCloud so that the traffic hits the 8001 port, not the 8080 port?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean exactly by Google Cloud Platform?

If you are using the AppEngine Launcher you can change the port by editing the ini file directly:

```
C:/Users/username/Google/google_appengine_projects.ini
```

Comment: Thanks! I mean the java apps you can deploy on https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine. The path of the gcloud sdk on my PC is different, it looks like: C:\Users\levallois\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine
There is no google_appengine_projects.ini file in the folders as far as I could see.

Comment: Why not running the server on the port of your preference:

     `$ dev_appserver.py --port=<port> <app name>`

Comment: Not sure how / where I would type this command - the deployment process is managed by a push from a GCloud console on my local PC (a bit like git), not from a command line interface where I'd be able to directly launch my jar file

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42741012/3615567) and the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#port_forwarding)