# Google App Engine two ports on same application

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I want to run a node js application on Google App Engine but my application is currently running two protocols, on two different ports. One of them is the port 8080 (which is required to work on Google App Engine) and the other one is 1883, a mqtt server. Looking the documentation, I couldn't find anything to make this works, actually, the server starts without errors but of course I can't connect to the port 1883, only the http and https.

I need to know if this is possible at all and if is, how do I forward that port or proxy that?

My app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: comms-server
network:
  name: default
  subnetwork_name: default
  forwarded_ports:
    - 1883/tcp
```

Also, my VPC configuration is:

[image]

Comment: Try [forwarding the port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42741012/3058302) in your `app.yaml` file. Bear in mind that this is only applicable to App Engine Flexible, not Standard

Comment: Didn't work.. I forwarded the port, opened on the VPC, configured everything right on the app.yaml file, actually I tried every configuration possible, still can't connect on port 1883. I'll update the question showing my app.yaml file and the VPC configuration

Comment: Now in 2020, did you managed to have 2 ports on the same application? @GustavoMendonça

Comment: thinking of the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
network:
  forwarded_ports:
  - 1883
  instance_tag: comms-server
```

And:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-comms-server \
  --allow tcp:1883 \
  --target-tags comms-server \
  --description "Allow  traffic on port 1883"
```

Comment: It just doesn't work.. I can't connect to that port. Tried your configuration, added the rule, changed the priority to maximum, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What [@avivl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500442/avivl) should work but there is an extra step, you will have to connect using the AppEngine instance's IP address. The *appspot.com domain won't work with the port. It's a bug see here - [server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1031625/google-app-engine-https-listening-ports-8443-or-3443)