# Docker | Google Cloud - Fails when react start

Tags: reactjs, docker, google-app-engine, docker-compose, mern

I'm trying to dockerize a `MERN` stack but when the time comes when react has to start, the container exit with status 0.
This is the log error:

[image: Docker error]

This is the structure of my project:

```
- project
  - server
    - api
    api.yml
    server.js
    Dockerfile
  - www
    app.yml
    Dockerfile
  docker-compose.yml
```

The `www` folder contains the starter files the will be generate from `npx create-react-app www`.
The content of `server/Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/server
WORKDIR /usr/server

RUN npm install -g nodemon

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

the content of `www/Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/www/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/www/src/app

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

and, in the end the content of `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
     - 27017:27017
  api:
    build: ./server/
    ports:
      - "6200:6200"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/server
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
  www:
    build: ./www/
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./www:/usr/www/src/app
    depends_on:
      - api
```

Now, in the title I mention `Google Cloud`, because I tried to distribute the different "server" and "www" parts in my production environment. The distribution of `server` works correctly but`www` fails with this error:

[image: GCloud Error]

The errors that are generated by `Docker` and `Google Cloud` seem very similar or am I wrong? Could it be a reaction problem or am I wrong in both cases?

I also leave the contents of the `app.yaml` and`api.yaml` files.
`app.yaml`

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

# Only for developing
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
  - url: /
    static_dir: build
```

The content of the `api.yaml` file is the same as that of `app.yaml` but without the `handlers` section.

Comment: You need to use runtime: custom for deploying docker containers. Only one container per service and they have to listen in port 8080. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build

Comment: @Juancki Yes, I know but when I try to deploy on GCP I remove the Dockerfile

Comment: How do you deploy exactly?

Comment: @Juancki Entering in the project folder and run this command: `gcloud app deploy www/app.yaml`

Comment: Each server should still listen to the 8080 port

Comment: @Juancki How can I set the port for each `services`? Directly in the `yaml` file?

Comment: Have you checked the deployment errors in Stackdriver Logging?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211874/discussion-between-juancki-and-th3g3ntl3man).

Comment: The 8080 port has to work, but you can add other services (ports) to the same app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54739590/google-app-engine-two-ports-on-same-application